# Problem with displaying images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have developed an iPad app using core data to store employee details. I have only three fields: Name, id and department. On launching the application the names are displayed in a table view and on clicking in any row, the respective id and department is displayed in the detail view.

Now I want to display picture of the employees in detail view too but not by storing them in core data. I have a subfolder named "Images" in the resources folder in which the pictures are stored in order of the names displayed in the table view.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: So the image filenames contain the employee names ? Like "John Smith.jpg" ?

Comment: Yes. The image filenames contain the employee names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the static method `[NSBundle mainBundle]` to get an object that represents your application bundle. With this you can then call the instance method `- (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)extension` to get a path to the image you have stored. Once you have the path, you can create an instance of *UIImage* with the image path. You can then create a *UIImageView* (which could be done in interface builder if you wish), of which you can then set the image to your instance of *UIImage*.

For example:

```
NSString* pathToImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pictureOfJohn" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathToImage];
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageView.image = image;
[myEnclosingView addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

Note that the creation and adding of the *imageView* could be done in interface builder.

Comment: One point where i need clarification is that don't i need an array as i have multiple images. And how would the above code link each row with the respective picture?

Comment: There are many ways of going about this. One might be to store the name of the image file in your Core Data model. Then you could use that in the `pathForResource:` function. At the time that you go load the detailed view you could create an image using this path that's created using the information in your model to get the correct image?

Comment: You do know that you don't need to use the bundle for that ? A simple `[UIImage imageNamed:@"pictureOfJohn.jpg"]` does the same job.

Comment: I didn't! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You should read something about transient properties of CoreData entities. You can easily add property image for example, which is transient (= does not store values to underlying persistent store), which can read/write your images directly from your file system. In other words, you can have everything in one place and no entity in one class, image handling in another, etc.